# Static text in a select

Tags: javascript, html, css, select

I want my select to always show the same text, but "keep" the selected option value.
So e.g. my select always shows text "Language", but when I get the value of it in JS, it will return the value of selected option.
How do I achieve this? If there's no possibility for pure HTML + CSS, vanilla JS will do.

Edit: I want this because when i choose a value, I have a list of input boxes which get filled by this. They are then changeable; this select is only used to set the "base" of these inputs. I want this select to always show the same
text because I don't want to end up in a situation where select shows different text than actually the text in inputs that will be used.

Answer:

```html
            <select id="mySelect">
              <option value="" hidden>Language</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
```

```js
document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener('change', showSameValue)

function showSameValue() {
  let select = document.getElementById('mySelect')
  let firstOption = select.querySelector('option')
  firstOption.value = select.value
  select.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

Comment: Can you give another example? I'm not sure a <select> will do what you want; wondering if you might need a hidden input. What's the point of always showing the same text?

Comment: I want to use my select in a way, that when I choose an option, some fields on my site will fill in, only it. So it will better look stylistically if it always shows the same text

Comment: It seems like what you're asking for is a `label`, just positioned over the `select`. Then give the `option`s a healthy padding-left. It would be nice if you could show a sketch or some kind of picture of what you want though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `change` event, you can capture the selected value then simply set the first option as selected and set its value to the selected value.

```js
select = document.querySelector("select");
first = select.querySelector("option");

select.addEventListener("change",function(el){
    first.value = el.target.value;
    el.target.querySelector("option").setAttribute("selected",false)
    el.target.selectedIndex = 0;
    console.log(first.value);
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">Language</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird behavior but it can be done by

- adding a hidden input element next to select
- add the event listener to select (onchange) that would change the value of the hidden element and reset select to desired value 'Languages'

The key would be to have proper fields names, so when submitting the form select could be omitted and hidden would prevail.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this, <del>but using just a `<select>` would not be possible</del>, **I would not advise this on an accessibility UX principal**.

One option would be to use a `<span>` or `<div>` that when clicked shows the options.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selected value in a variable to meet your requirement and then use it wherever you need.

```
<select name="select" onchange="func(this.value);">
<option value="value1">Display always</option>
<option value="value2">Random Value</option>            
</select>
```

And here's the Js function

```js
var selected = "";
function func(selectedValue) {
  document.getElementById( "select").selectedIndex = "0";
  selected = selectedValue; // Use this after final selection
}
```